# Disable Apache Spark metrics collector (for CI)

Tags: apache-spark

Running Apache Spark in a CI environment, I try to disable all unnecessary Spark features (such as web UI, metrics...) because it throws lot of `org.jacoco.agent` exceptions.

Is it possible to disable it (with Spark 1.6.x)?

Comment: My guess is that you should be able to configure jacoco plugin to ignore specific classes/packages instead of disabling Spark features.

Comment: Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I don't know, as I need to dive deeper into some specifics of how you run/use it (Maven, Gradle, Sbt). But it should be pretty straightforward if you look into Jacoco's documentation, as for Maven's example: https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html